# bash scripting. Pattern matching

Tags: bash, shell

I have some code

```
#!/bin/ksh
##########################################################################

$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar SocketListener.jar 8182 &    
while[[ ??? ]] do;
sleep 1
done

next_command
```

Next command must be executed, after loading SocketListener.
I have method  **GetJavaID() {}**
that can get SocketListener PID. I need something that can compare $(GetJavaID) and pattern[0-9] in *while* loop.
In while loop should be check: Has PID $(GetJavaID) created or not?

Comment: I can't help noticing that you're asking about bash, but running your script in ksh ... not quite the same thing!

Comment: Anyway, I don't get it? If you already *know* the PID, why do you have to see if it's running? Either it's running, or else it doesn't have a PID yet, surely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say

```
while ! ps -p $(some method that returns the PID you want) 1>/dev/null ; do
    sleep 1
done
```

`ps` with `-p pid` will return success if a pid matches and failure otherwise.

Comment: You can also validate a process id with `kill -n 0 $PID`, which avoids external commands.

Comment: @Idelic: What external commands? Surely you don't mean `ps`. The requestor knows the PID only by running some command, so I incorporated that fact in to the solution. Replacing the above with `while kill -n 0 $(...) ; do` is not much different

Comment: It is different in that it doesn't run external commands. And I do mean `ps`.

Comment: @Idelic: `kill` is only a builtin sometimes.

Comment: It is a builtin much more often than `ps`, and it is a builtin for `bash`, which is tagged in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the PID of the "most recently executed background (asynchronous) command" using the "$!"

so this should do the trick:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar SocketListener.jar 8182 &
JAVAPID=$!
while ps -p ${JAVAPID} > /dev/null
do
  sleep 1
done
echo "done"
```

i redirect the output of "ps" to /dev/null to avoid unneccessary output.

apart from that i fail to understand why you need to background one process only to wait for it afterwards.
the following should be equivalent:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar SocketListener.jar 8182
echo "done"
```

unless, of course, you want to do something more between starting you process and printing "done".

Answer (score 0):

Greg's wiki to the rescue. In [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#Starting_a_.22daemon.22_and_checking_whether_it_started_successfully):

> `kill -0 $PID` will check to see whether a signal is deliverable (*i.e.*, the process still exists). If you need to check on a single child process asynchronously, that's the most portable solution. You might also be able to use the `wait` shell command to block until the child (or children) terminate -- it depends on what your program has to do.

And

> There is no such thing as "the daemon started up successfully", and if your specific daemon were to have a relevant definition to that statement, it would be so completely daemon-specific, that there is no generic way for us to tell you how to check for that condition.

I don't understand why you accepted the solution you did. First, if you want to wait for the process to *terminates*, there's no need to background it. And `while ! ps -p $PID` is going to run until the process *terminates* (just like the much simpler `wait` would do), so it all boils down to a single line:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar SocketListener.jar 8182
```

Answer (score -1):

use PS command to get list of all running process's PID and grep for the PID. The number of output must be greater than one to ensure that PID is running( Grepping the PID will be one process listed in the output so we are checking for more than one output). Use wc command to get the number of output. So the command will be

```
 result=`ps axu | grep -c $(GerJavaID)`  #-c will make it to return number of output lines
 if [ $result -gt 1 ]
 then
   echo "Process Running"
 fi
```

Comment: This has several of the classic "don't do that" shell scripting antipatterns.  http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: I have improved it. Still you find some antipatterns ?